# How to align checkboxes vertically in a non-editable form?

Tags: checkbox, sapui5

SAPUI5 simple form does not make the checkboxes vertically center align.
[image: simple form check box]

Here is the code:

```xml
<form:SimpleForm title="{i18n>wizardDateLocation}"
  minWidth="1024"
  editable="false"
  layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
>
  <Label text="{i18n>wholeDay}"/>
  <CheckBox selected="{/IsAllDay}" editable="false"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>date}" visible="{= ${/IsAllDay}}" required="true"/>
  <Text text="{/Start}" visible="{= ${/IsAllDay}}"/>
  <HBox></HBox>
  <Label text="{i18n>from}" visible="{= !${/IsAllDay} }" required="true"/>
  <Text text="{/Start}" visible="{= !${/IsAllDay} }"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>to}" visible="{= !${/IsAllDay} }" required="true"/>
  <Text text="{/End}" visible="{= !${/IsAllDay} }"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>isOnlineMeeting}" required="false"/>
  <CheckBox selected="{/IsOnlineMeeting}" editable="false"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>location}" required="{= !${/IsOnlineMeeting} }"/>
  <Text text="{/LocationName}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>weblink}" required="{/IsOnlineMeeting}"/>
  <Text text="{/WebLink}"/>
  <Link press="editStepTwo" text="{i18n>edit}"/>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI5 provides **`displayOnly`** property for controls that are usually editable but occur in a non-editable form.

Hence, instead of making the whole form editable, which is contradictory since the rest of the form fields are just texts (non-editable), try enabling `displayOnly` on CheckBoxes.

```xml
<form:SimpleForm editable="false">
  <!-- ... -->
  <CheckBox displayOnly="true" />
  <!-- ... -->
</form:SimpleForm>
```

From the [API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.CheckBox):

> #### `displayOnly`
>
> When set to `true`, the `CheckBox` is not interactive, not editable, not focusable and not in the tab chain. **This setting is used for forms** in review mode.
>   When the property enabled is set to false this property has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason. Somehow strange but if we make the simple form not editable then this problem appears. The solution is:

```
<form:SimpleForm editable="true">
```

[image]

Comment: Your form is not editable, so don't set editable to true.