# Issue with Progress Indicator alignment in sap.ui.layout.form.(Simple)Form

Tags: sapui5

The `ProgressIndicator` should be aligned vertically in a same row.

**Current output:**
[image]

```xml
<form:SimpleForm id="idSimpleForm"
  editable="false"
  layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
  maxContainerCols="2"
  columnsM="2"
  singleContainerFullSize="false"
  labelSpanS="5"
>
  <Label text="Lines Of Code"/>
  <Text text="{...}"/>
  <Label text="CSS"/>
  <ProgressIndicator percentValue="100" state="Success"/>
  <Text text="{...}"/>
  <Label text="XML"/>
  <ProgressIndicator percentValue="30" state="Success"/>
  <Text text="{...}"/>
  <Label text="JavaScript"/>
  <ProgressIndicator percentValue="20" state="Success"/>
  <Text text="{...}"/>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

**Desired output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `displayOnly` to `true`.

```xml
<form:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
  <Label text="CSS"/>
  <ProgressIndicator displayOnly="true" displayValue="14k" percentValue="100" state="Information" />
  <Label text="XML"/>
  <ProgressIndicator displayOnly="true" displayValue="7.3k" percentValue="30" state="Information" />
  <Label text="JavaScript"/>
  <ProgressIndicator displayOnly="true" displayValue="2.1k" percentValue="20" state="Information" />
</form:SimpleForm>
```

[image: UI5 sap.m.ProgressIndicator properly aligned with labels]
<sup>From: https://jsbin.com/huvokeg/edit?js,output</sup>

Avoid custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the progress indicator control and redefine the style accordingly. e.g. class name is `progress-indicator`.

```css
.progress-indicator {
  margin: 0px !important;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 1px !important;
}

.progress-indicator .sapMPIBarPositive {
  background-color: #91C8F6;
}

.progress-indicator .sapMPIBar {
  border-radius: 1px !important;
}

.progress-indicator .sapMPIBarRemaining {
  border-top-right-radius: 0rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/meviqeb/edit?html,css,output